# Google Event Tracking Multiple Forms

Tags: events, analytics, tracking

I have a few different contact forms (all using contact form 7) and would like to track the submission action on each of them. In the GA tracking code, I added the following:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'PFStandard');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'PFAdvanced');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'PFTrainer');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'SnowcatBasic');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'SnowcatEnhanced');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'WinterSurvival');
ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'GeneralContact');
```

I also added snippets to individual contact forms. For example, in the winter survival's additional setting, I added:

```
on_sent_ok: "ga('send', 'event', 'Forms', 'Submit', 'WinterSurvival');"
```

I thought the labels would track only that form, but instead it's tracking each form submission 7 times... What should I do?